# The_{\text{legend}}: 'legend' is aliased

Tags: subscripts, aliasing

Using Python and Matplotlib to create a plot with a legend given by the expression in the title of this question. 'The' is rendered ok, ie, in italics, but, when magnified (zoomed) 'legend' becomes aliased, in normal text.

As a workaround, is there a way of rewriting this Latex to specify normal text for the subscript in a different way that would not result in aliasing?

Or something else we could do that is altogether more clever?

Edit: This question relates to one on StackOverflow, at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47778208/rendering-of-axis-label-using-latex-in-matplotlib/47779147, and to my attempt to answer it there.

Comment: Though Matplotlib is not exactly the topic of this stackexchange site, you should still provide a minimal example of your code which recreates the issues you're facing. Note however that I think this is off-topic here and should be asked elsewhere (stackoverflow?).

Comment: @Skillmon: Thanks for responding. A broader question has been asked on SO; I tried to answer it there. However, the OP pointed out that the code in the title here would normally do what he intends. This set me wondering whether there might be an alternative way of writing the Latex to get the same result.

Comment: My answer to the linked question would most likely be the following (I did not take a deep look into it, this is based on assumptions): "Most likely the pixelation is done because the fontsize you're requiring isn't available. This is a common limitation of the computer modern font. You should add a LaTeX preamble to your matplotlib stuff with the following line: `mpl.rcParams.update("pgf.preamble": [r"\usepackage{lmodern}"])`"

Comment: So my answer to this question is: You can change the LaTeX stuff with `mpl.rcParams.update` specifying a LaTeX preamble.

Comment: Note however that there most likely is a LaTeX preamble and using only `r"\usepackage{lmodern}"` might break other stuff relying on that preamble, so you should test that prior to answering :) And keep in mind that I'm not a hundred percent sure that cmodern is the culprit here.

Comment: More correct would be `mpl.rcParams.update({"pgf.preamble": [r"\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}",r"\usepackage{lmodern,mathtools}"]})`. At least `amsmath` is required (loaded by `mathtools`). I also forgot the curly braces around the argument of `mpl.rcParams.update` because it expects a dictionary.

Comment: @Skillmon: Thanks again. If the OP doesn't seem to be finding all of these comments, I will refer him here again.

Comment: Whatever code generated that is wrong anyway, `\text ` should never ever be used like that. It ought to be `\textup` or `\textnormal ` sadly a very common mistake.

Comment: @daleif: My use of Latex is minimal. Can you say why, or point me to an already answered question that answers that question? Thanks for the comment.

Comment: The command text is meant for textual comments in displayed math. As such it follows the style of the surrounding text, so if used in an italic context the output from text will be italic. This is not what you want from a textual index like this, it has to be upright no matter what.